# conky attempt to call nil value

Tags: linux, x11, conky, lua

I've been tweaking my `conky` config and getting the error

```
conky: llua_do_call: function conky_cpu execution failed: attempt to call a nil value
```

The function `conky_cpu` resides in `~/.conky_cpu.lua`. That feels strange to me because `conky` works fine when the `.conky_part.lua` is not loaded. Moreover, the same error happens even when the `.conky_part.lua` is empty.

```
lua_load = '~/.conky_cpu.lua',
lua_load = '~/.conky_part.lua',
```

Comment: You could add a `print(conky_cpu)` at various parts of the lua code to see if it gets changed at all.

Comment: @meuh you mean some kind of cache there? I've never seen that before when loading an empty files gives you errors.

Comment: Without any code, or configuration you changed, it is very hard to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems trying to load multiple Lua files, finally stumbling onto the following, which worked:

```
lua_load = '~/.conky_cpu.lua ~/.conky_part.lua',
```